# In drupal, how do I add a favor on the content?

Tags: drupal, addition

In drupal, the visitor can visit all kinds of news pages, and there is one button saying like or favor, once the user likes this article, he will press the favor, and this article will be stored, and later on he can review his likes

e.x just like in stackoverflow, on the left side bar, these is a star button, allowing other users to 'like' it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module.  It comes default with a "Bookmark" flag that users can use to mark nodes as favorites.  Otherwise, you can create your own type of flag.